# Files in the folder don't appear on the host after mounting to container

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have dedicated **data volume container** which map source code to php container and **data volume** which map another one folder to **data volume container** file structure.

common-services.yml

```
code:
  image: debian:jessie
  volumes:
    - ../:/var/www
```

docker-compose-dev.yml

```
php:
  extends:
    file: common-services.yml
    service: php
  volumes_from:
    - code
  links:
    - mysql
  volumes:
    - "~/Projects/test-sampledata:/var/www/app/code/TEST/SampleData/"
```

On the host machine I see all files&folders of **/var/www** but not sub-folder **/var/www/app/code/TEST/SampleData/**. When I enter php container I see file structure as expected.

The question is why **/var/www/app/code/TEST/SampleData/** with its sub-folders don't map to the host.

OS: Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS

Thanks in advance !

Comment: I see your update shows my answer no longer applies. Can you confirm you are running this with a local docker host (`unset DOCKER_HOST`), that `ls ~/Projects/test-sampledata` returns the content you're expecting, and that you are running a relatively current version of docker-compose (`docker-compose --version`)? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running on MacOS or Windows, you need the host volume within the /Users folder. Each of these implementations run a VM under the covers to provide the docker host on Linux, and these VM's mount /Users as a share to your parent OS by default. This can be modified in the settings of Docker if needed (or at least it can be on the recent MacOS releases).